# SSL with a CNAME pointing to Cloudflare

Tags: ssl, dns, cloudflare, cname, ipfs

I'm trying to host a static website on IPFS by pinning the content on my IPFS node and pointing my DNS to `cloudflare-ipfs.com`. I have my CNAME pointing to `cloudflare-ipfs.com.` and the `_dnslink` properly set up. I use Namecheap for DNS. HTTP works great.

However I'm following the guide on Cloudflare but having trouble with the [SSL part here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/distributed-web/ipfs-gateway/connecting-website#make-it-all-secure).

Specifically it says:

> Cloudflare will issue you a free SSL certificate for `your.website`, which allows users to load `https://your.website`.

It's really unclear how I'm issued this free SSL certificate so I'm trying to debug what the next steps are.

Currently going to `https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/<my-hash>` works fine. However going to `https://mywebsite.com` will give me an insecure padlock warning, and if I click "accept risk and continue to website" I get a 403 Cloudflare error. Research online shows Cloudflare gives a 403 error when the SSL certificate isn't matching for subdomains. The certificate that is served is indeed only valid for `cloudflare-ipfs.com` and `*.cloudflare-ipfs.com`, which matches my experience that the Cloudflare URL works, but `https://mywebsite.com` does not.

If the CNAME points to Cloudflare, wouldn't it be a Cloudflare server providing the certificate? If so, how would I be able to get Cloudflare to provide an SSL certificate including my website domain? (i.e. it's their server). Is their guide suggesting that I need to sign up for an SSL certificate through them, (and then they will do something in the background that serves the certificate for my site)? Or is there a way to get an SSL certificate from Namecheap and have cloudflare-ipfs serve it?

Comment: Did you set your domain to DNS only? instead of Proxied? It needs to be proxied otherwise you need to set your own ssl in the origin server.

Comment: Their documentation does seem pretty vague on this point. I believe the root issue is that the domain must be added to your Cloudflare account however. It can't use the Namecheap nameservers.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/201720164-Creating-a-Cloudflare-account-and-adding-a-website

Comment: I was using proxied. I had to create a cloudflare account to get the SSL cert. I had to point the name servers to cloudflare ones

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Meson Network](https://meson.network/) ipfs public gateway.

Origin IPFS link

```
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmTiBvaKcCk7LU8zLsKdjrjnPhpQBiWp14Nb5PtffD6xid
```

Accelerated link by meson

```
https://coldcdn.com/api/cdn/4wdhj2/QmTiBvaKcCk7LU8zLsKdjrjnPhpQBiWp14Nb5PtffD6xid
```